# Prevent duplicate results with where in statement with CI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have an issue with my `where in` sql statement. Ill show my tables first and then explain what I am trying to do and why I am getting the issue.

```
Table1

id primary key
title


Table2

id primary key
vid foreign key


Table3

vid primary key
vegetable
```

So above are my tables and heres my CodeIgniter SQL

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Table1');
$this->db->join('Table2', 'Table2.id = Table1.id');
$this->db->join('Table3', 'Table3.vid = Table2.vid');
$this->db->where_in('vegetable', $veg);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

The result will be returned to my controller and sent to my view where it gets outputted like this:

```
if (isset($results)){
            foreach($results as $row){
                $id = $row->id;
                echo $row->title;
            }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to get the `title` from `Table1` with a few joins and using the `vegetable` column to search in. So what I am having an issue with is if in `Table2` the `id` holds 2 `vid`s and both are in the `$veg` array it will cause the results to duplicate because the item comes up twice even though its the same `id`. So my question is how can I prevent it from duplicating?

Example:
`$veg` would be an array so for the example lets say it has the following values `potatoe`, `cabbage` and `lettuce` and each of these values in the third table would have the following values respectively `1`,`2`,`3`. Now the issue I have is if I have the `vid` repeated on one `id` I will have the `title` shown more than once so say the `id` is `1` and this has `vid` of `1` and `2` the `title` will be repeated twice because it gets found twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$this->db->distinct();` in your active record query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Table1');
$this->db->join('Table2', 'Table2.id = Table1.id');
$this->db->join('Table3', 'Table3.vid = Table2.vid');
$this->db->where_in('vegetable', $veg);
$this->db->distinct();
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

*Example from Active Record manual*

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->get('table');

// Produces: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table
```

[**See Active Reocord Reference**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, I tried it in phpmyadmin as well to check that it wasn't a fault with my CI functions but I still got the values repeated.

Comment: Although there is no use of group function here but you use `$this->db->group_by("Table1.id");` instead of distinct clause

Comment: Thanks that solved it, can you give me to documentation if possible please, and a quick explanation if possible.

Comment: You can visit [*Mysql GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to see how it should be actually used and in CI i have gave you the reference already

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($results)){
            $results = array_unique($results);
            foreach($results as $row){
                $id = $row->id;
                echo $row->title;
            }
}
```

[PHP: array_unique - Manual](http://php.net/function.array-unique) php function removes duplicates from an array.

Comment: Doing this returns an error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`